# I can't figure out how to get my monkey and dog lists to print as anything but hex codes. I think I need a toString method but I can't get it to work

Tags: java, tostring

I'm working on a project for a java class and I'm stuck on this issue. When I run the program and test menu options 4 and 5 I get lists to print but they print as [Dog@42a57993, Dog@75b84c92, Dog@6bc7c054] instead of printing the actual information from the arrays.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    private static ArrayList<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    private static ArrayList<Monkey> monkeyList = new ArrayList<Monkey>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        initializeDogList();
        initializeMonkeyList();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner class object
        char option;
        
        do // loop until user quits program
        {
            displayMenu();
            option = input.next().charAt(0);
            if (option == '1') { // intakeNewDog method is called
                intakeNewDog(input);
            }
            
            else if (option == '2') { // intakeNewMonkey method is called
                intakeNewMonkey(input);

            }
            
            else if (option == '3') { // reserveAnimal method is called
                reserveAnimal(input);
            }
            
            else if (option == '4') { // printAnimals method is called to print the dog list
                printAnimals(option);
            }
            
            else if (option == '5') { // printAnimals method is called to print the monkey list
                printAnimals(option);
            }
            
            else if (option == '6') { // printAnimals method is called to print all available animals
                printAnimals(option);
            }
            
            else if (option == 'q') { // exit message prints and application stops running
                System.out.print("You have exited the application.");
                break;
            }
            
            else { // in the event of an invalid input, tells user and prompts for a new input
                System.out.print("You have entered an invalid input. Please enter a valid input.");
            }
        }
        while (option != 'q');
    }

    // This method prints the menu options
    public static void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tRescue Animal System Menu");
        System.out.println("[1] Intake a new dog");
        System.out.println("[2] Intake a new monkey");
        System.out.println("[3] Reserve an animal");
        System.out.println("[4] Print a list of all dogs");
        System.out.println("[5] Print a list of all monkeys");
        System.out.println("[6] Print a list of all animals that are not reserved");
        System.out.println("[q] Quit application");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter a menu selection");
    }


    // Adds dogs to a list for testing
    public static void initializeDogList() {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("Spot", "German Shepherd", "male", "1", "25.6", "05-12-2019", "United States", "intake", false, "United States");
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Rex", "Great Dane", "male", "3", "35.2", "02-03-2020", "United States", "Phase I", false, "United States");
        Dog dog3 = new Dog("Bella", "Chihuahua", "female", "4", "25.6", "12-12-2019", "Canada", "in service", true, "Canada");

        dogList.add(dog1);
        dogList.add(dog2);
        dogList.add(dog3);
    }


    // Adds monkeys to a list for testing
    //Optional for testing
    public static void initializeMonkeyList() {
        Monkey monkey1 = new Monkey("Joe", "male", "2", "6.5", "04-18-2021", "United States", "in service", false, "United States", "Spider Monkey", "16.6", "16.4", "19.0");
        Monkey monkey2 = new Monkey("Bob", "male", "3", "8.5", "07-20-2020", "Brazil", "Phase 4", true, "United States", "Capuchin", "19", "19.4", "15.5");
        Monkey monkey3 = new Monkey("Lisa", "female", "1", "20.0", "07-07-2022", "Nairobi", "in service", true, "Nairobi", "Howler Monkry", "25.2", "14", "13.4");

        monkeyList.add(monkey1);
        monkeyList.add(monkey2);
        monkeyList.add(monkey3);
    
    }


    // Complete the intakeNewDog method
    // The input validation to check that the dog is not already in the list
    // is done for you
    public static void intakeNewDog(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("What is the dog's name?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        for(Dog dog: dogList) {
            if(dog.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("\n\nThis dog is already in our system\n\n");
                return; //returns to menu
            }
        }

        System.out.println("What is the dog's breed?"); // this code is for adding a new dog
        String breed = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the dog's gender?");
        String gender = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the dog's age?");
        String age = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the dog's weight?");
        String weight = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the dog's acquisition date?");
        String acquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the dog's acquisition country?");
        String acquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the dog's training status?");
        String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is this dog reserved?");
        boolean reserved = scanner.nextBoolean();
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Which country is the dog in service?");
        String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
        
        Dog dog4 = new Dog(name, breed, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate, acquisitionCountry, trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry);
        dogList.add(dog4);
        System.out.println("Your entry has been added to the Dog List.");
    }


    public static void intakeNewMonkey(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's name?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        for(Monkey monkey: monkeyList) {
            if(monkey.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("\n\nThis monkey is already in our system\n\n");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's gender?"); // the following is to add a new monkey to the system
        String gender = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's age?");
        String age = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's weight?");
        String weight = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's acquisition date?");
        String acquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's acquisition country?");
        String acquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's training status?");
        String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is this monkey reserved?");
        boolean reserved = scanner.nextBoolean();
        System.out.println("Which country is the monkey in service?");
        String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's species?");
        String species = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the tail length?");
        String tailLength = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the height?");
        String height = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the body length?");
        String bodyLength = scanner.nextLine();
        
        Monkey monkey4 = new Monkey(name, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate, acquisitionCountry, trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry, species, tailLength, height, bodyLength);
        monkeyList.add(monkey4);
        System.out.println("Your entry has been added to the Monkey List.");
  }
    

        
        public static void reserveAnimal(Scanner scanner) {
            scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter animal type: ");
            String animalType = scanner.nextLine();
            if (animalType.equalsIgnoreCase("Monkey")) {
                System.out.println("Enter the monkey's acquisition country: ");
                String country = scanner.nextLine();
                for (Monkey obj: monkeyList) {
                    if (obj.getAcquisitionLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(country)) {
                        obj.setReserved(true);
                        System.out.println("This monkey is now reserved.");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void printAnimals(char option) { // print options for dogList, monkeyList, all available animals
            if (option == '4') {
                System.out.println(dogList);
            }
            else if (option == '5') {
                System.out.println (monkeyList);
            }
            else if (option == '6') {
                for (int i = 0; i < dogList.size(); i++) {
                    if (dogList.get(i).getTrainingStatus().equals("in service") && dogList.get(i).getReserved()==false) {
                        System.out.println(dogList.get(i));
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < monkeyList.size(); i++) {
                    if (monkeyList.get(i).getTrainingStatus().equals("in service") && monkeyList.get(i).getReserved()==false) {
                        System.out.println(monkeyList.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }

        }

}
```

I've tried to search for information on implementing a toString method to see if I could figure it out, but have not been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dog` doesn't define a toString method, and the default toString method just returns the class name and the hashCode of the object. You just need to make a new method inside `Dog` looking like this:

```java
@Override // <- technically optional, but very recommended
public String toString() {
    return "What you want to show up when printing a Dog";
}
```

Anything returned in this method will show up when printing a `Dog`, you can make the returned value anything you'd like. Returning null will probably cause issues at some point tho, so don't do that.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I was trying to add the method in the driver class which I suppose explains why I couldn't get it working. Now I just need to format it so it looks nice when printed. Thanks for your help!